# Make the last div has only border-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have bunch of divs with the same class...Here is the code

```
<div class="login-input"><span>Username</span><input type="text"></div>
<div class="login-input last-login-input"><span>Password</span><input type="text"></div>
```

all the divs has only one same class, that was login-input
then i want to add another class for the last div, which is last-login-input that specify border-bottom for the last div
this is the code

```
.last-login-input{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: #BABABA;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

and here is my .login-input class

```
#wrapper #login-form .login-input{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 0;
border-color: #BABABA;
width: 400px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

But when I add .last-login-input to my last div it doesn't show the border-bottom...

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ymnd4mot/)

Comment: Wow...thanks vitorino :D

Comment: It does show Your code is fine [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLt7jfes/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS code for that:

```css
.input {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
}
.last {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" />
<input type="password" class="input last" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.login-input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
  border-color: #BABABA;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.last-login-input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #BABABA;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-input"><span>Username</span>

  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="login-input last-login-input"><span>Password</span>

  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change border-width 1px 1px 1px

The third is for down pad

Comment: it will extra bottom border for the first div